# Find OS by interpreting TCP/IP fingerprints when using nmap

Tags: linux, windows, networking, nmap, fingerprint

When I ran the command: `nmap -O ip_address` to identify the OS, I got the following result:

```
OS:SCAN(V=5.05BETA1%D=8/23%OT=22%CT=1%CU=42341%PV=N%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=4A91CB
    OS:90%P=xxxx)SEQ(SP=C9%GCD=1%ISR=CF%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=A)OPS(O1
    OS:=M400CST11NW5%O2=M400CST11NW5%O3=M400CNNT11NW5%O4=M400CST11NW5%O5=M400CS
    OS:T11NW5%O6=M400CST11)WIN(W1=8000%W2=8000%W3=8000%W4=8000%W5=8000%W6=8000)
    OS:ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=8018%O=M400CNNSNW5%CC=N%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S+
    OS:%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=8000%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%O=M400CST11NW
    OS:5%RD=0%Q=)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W
    OS:=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)
    OS:T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R=Y%DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%U
    OS:N=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=40%CD=S)
```

How can I find the most likely OS on this scanned computer? How can I interpret this result? What suggests that the OS may be Linux for example, and what suggests that it may be another OS, for example Windows? I am trying hard to understand it. Please help me. Thanks in advance